# How to change default colorscale for a scatter3D plot in Plotly.Blazor

Tags: plotly, blazor-server-side

I would like to set a different colorscale for a 3D scatter plot in Plotly.Blazor. I could find no examples of how to do this (only examples were in python and javascript), so have tried to carefully read the documentation. What I am doing is this:

When I define the layout, I create a new "Colorway" with a new "ColorAxis" in order to set AutoColorScale to false and the colorscale to "Jet":

```
Layout lo3Dscatter = new Layout
        {
            Title = new Title
            {
                Text = "<b>Map of Readings in 3D Space</b>"
            },
            Scene = new[]
            {
                new Scene()
                {
                    XAxis = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.XAxis(){Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.XAxisLib.Title(){Text = "X position (mm)"}},
                    YAxis = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.YAxis(){Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.YAxisLib.Title(){Text = "Y position (mm)"}},
                    ZAxis = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.ZAxis(){Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.SceneLib.ZAxisLib.Title(){Text = "Z position (mm)"}}
                }
            }, 
            Colorway = new[]
                {
                new ColorAxis()
                {  
                    AutoColorScale=false,
                    ColorScale="Jet"
                }                
            },            
            Margin = new Margin
            {
                L = 65,
                R = 50,
                B = 65,
                T = 90
            }
        };
```

I have also tried explicitly setting the surface color when adding a new Scatter3D series as below:

```
graphTraces3Dscatter.Add(new Scatter3D()
{
          X = x.GetRange(previousIndex, index - previousIndex).Cast<object>().ToList(),
          Y = y.GetRange(previousIndex, index - previousIndex).Cast<object>().ToList(),
          Z = z.GetRange(previousIndex, index - previousIndex).Cast<object>().ToList(),
          Name = "Reading > " + delta.ToString(),
          Mode = Plotly.Blazor.Traces.Scatter3DLib.ModeFlag.Markers,
          Opacity = System.Convert.ToDecimal(0.9),
          SurfaceColor=Color.Red
});
```

But the color scale stubbornly persists as the default, which is a disadvantage in this application because it stops the customer being able to see where the best readings are at a glance, and instead they have to look back and forth at the default colour scale.

What am I missing?